# Cumulative sum of certain numbers in a dataframe ordered by date

Tags: r, dataframe, cumsum

I have a data frame with dates and values and want to a cumsum for only the positive numbers and one for only the negatives. The dates sometimes have the same date multiple times and then a couple of days are missing (no values = no row)

First I just tested a cumulative sum. These were cumulative but not in order of date:

```
df$cumsum <- cumsum(df$values) 
# or
df$cumsum  <- ave(df$values, FUN=cumsum)
# Should cumulate by date but did not in right order
df$cumsum   <- cumsum(df[order(df$date, df$values), "values"])
```

Finally found a solution which does the first step as I wanted (not really as I wanted to do in in a dataframe but does the job):

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[order(date), cumsum := cumsum(values)]
```

Great, however every attempt to filter values > 0 didn't work out. Finally I subsetted the data and got the result but it's not really what I wanted.

```
dt.pos <- data.table(subset(df, values> 0))
dt.pos[order(date), cumsum := cumsum(values)]

dt.neg <- data.table(subset(df, values < 0))
dt.neg[order(date), cumsum := cumsum(values)]
```

I'm looking for something as simple as the Python equivalent (with an ordered data frame):

```
df["cumsum_pos"] = df["values"][df["values"] > 0].cumsum()
df["cumsum_neg"] = df["values"][df["values"] < 0].cumsum()
```

/edit

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2016-12-08", "2016-12-07", "2016-12-05", "2017-01-05", 
                                  "2017-01-10", "2017-01-11", "2017-01-11")),
                 values = c(10, -10, 5, 5, -7, 8, 8))

# just the cumsum
# expected output = c(5, -5, 5, 10, 3, 11, 19)

df$cumsum <- cumsum(df$values)
# output = c(10, 0, 5, 10, 3, 11, 19)

df$cumsum  <- ave(df$values, FUN=cumsum)
# output = c(10, 0, 5, 10, 3, 11, 19)

df$cumsum <- cumsum(df[order(df$date, df$values), "values"])
# output = c(5, -5, 5, 10, 3, 11, 19) correct in this example
# doesn't work with dates in a different order 2016-12-31, 2016-12-30, ... 2015-12-31, 2015-12-30

# Now for just the positives
# expected output = c(10, 0, 5, 15, 15, 23, 31)
df$cumsum.pos[df$values > 0] <- cumsum(df[order(df$date, df$values), "values"][df$values > 0])
# output = c(5, NA, 15, 20, NA, 28, 36)

# And then the same with just the negatives
```

/edit

nicolas comment doesn't produce the correct output

```
df<-df[order(df$date),]
# values = c(5, -10, 10, 5, -7, 8, 8)
# expected output = c(5, 5, 15, 20, 20, 28, 36)
df$cumsum<-ave(df$values,df$values>0,FUN=cumsum)
# output = c(5, -10, 15, 20, -17, 28, 36)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: First order your data.frame: `df<-df[order(df$date),]` then use `ave`: `df$cumsum<-ave(df$value,df$value>0,FUN=cumsum)`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't give me exactly what I want since it add's the negatives too. Though it is a step in the right direction I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)

# Order by date
df <- df[order(date)]

# Perform the cumsum for positives and negatives separately
df[, expected := cumsum(values), by = sign(values)]

# Just for the negatives, get the previous positive value
df[, expected := ifelse(values > 0, expected, c(0, expected[-.N]))]

print(df)

         date values expected
1: 2016-12-05      5        5
2: 2016-12-07    -10        5
3: 2016-12-08     10       15
4: 2017-01-05      5       20
5: 2017-01-10     -7       20
6: 2017-01-11      8       28
7: 2017-01-11      8       36
```

Note that if there are more than one consecutive negative values, you have to repeat the operation. For instance, if your data frame is this one:

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2016-12-08", "2016-12-07", "2016-12-05", "2017-01-05","2017-01-10", "2017-01-10", "2017-01-11", "2017-01-11")), 
values = c(10, -10, 5, 5, -7, -15, 8, 8))
```

One single execution of the above code would produce the following output:

```
         date values expected
1: 2016-12-05      5        5
2: 2016-12-07    -10        5
3: 2016-12-08     10       15
4: 2017-01-05      5       20
5: 2017-01-10     -7       20
6: 2017-01-10    -15      -17
7: 2017-01-11      8       28
8: 2017-01-11      8       36
```

The value -17 would be wrong. In order to avoid this problem, you can repeat the process until there aren't any negative values left. So the full code would be:

```
df <- df[order(date)]
df[, expected := cumsum(values), by = sign(values)]

# If there are negative values, repeat the process
while(length(which(df$expected < 0))){
  df[, expected := ifelse(values > 0, expected, c(0, expected[-.N]))]
}

print(df)
         date values expected
1: 2016-12-05      5        5
2: 2016-12-07    -10        5
3: 2016-12-08     10       15
4: 2017-01-05      5       20
5: 2017-01-10     -7       20
6: 2017-01-10    -15       20
7: 2017-01-11      8       28
8: 2017-01-11      8       36
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But this was only the first part for which I already gave the solution. I need a cumsum for only the positive values.

Comment: @sezi80 Sorry, I didn't understand the question. I have updated the answer, it calculates the cumsum for positives and negatives separately. Is this your expected output?

Comment: OK my initial post seem to not be descriptive enough. I want a cumsum that is only positive, so a `geom_line()` will go straight up. Without subsetting the data. `expected output = c(5, 5, 15, 20, 20, 28, 36)`

Comment: You're welcome. With `expected[-.N]` I get the whole column `expected` (see `df$expected[-.N]`), so that I can prefix the sequence with a 0. The result is like "shifting" the whole column a single position downwards. You can get the same effect with `df[, expected := ifelse(values > 0, expected, shift(expected))]`